# nginx 301 redirect - google search console validation failed

Tags: nginx, redirect

I have some issues that are preventing indexing my website on Google.

My new website address is https://www.example.com.

In the google search console admin > pages > page with redirect > I have website URLs that failed validation:

```
http://example.com
https://example.com
http://www.example.com
```

The website is running on nginx server (CloudPanel).

I tried to add this rule:
server {
listen 80;
server_name http://example.com http://www.example.com https://example.com;
return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

Please correct me if I am doing something wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Please share the nginx config for the particular site and this http to https redirect will be already present in VHost config.

Comment: If you want to redirect www.example.com to example.com and vice versa, you can do it via the domain provider config itself.